# ElasticSearch: How to use filter_path parameter in POST body

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

So I can successfully do request like:

```
localhost:9200/filebeat-*/_count?filter_path=-_shards
{"query": {
    "match_phrase" : {
        "message" : "o hohoho"
    }
 }}
```

How I can move `filter_path=-_shards` into the request body to make it work?

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation code, still not possible in Elasticsearch 6.2:

> All REST APIs accept a filter_path parameter that can be used to
>   reduce the response returned by Elasticsearch

and it's impossible to include it into the request body, that's just not supported (to be honest, I'm not sure if it will **ever** be supported).

However, for some scenarios, you could limit response returned by Elasticsearch by using [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) (unfortunately, it's only applicable to returned fields of documents)